# Informatica | Performance impact for a Session with more number of Targets

Tags: informatica-powercenter

Have anyone faced a similar issue below:
Session with more number of targets.
TargetDB: Oracle
Target Schema: abc
Number of targets: 6

As per session logs, Writer thread is always busy 100%.
Writer volume is 5 million and takes 3.5 hours to complete.

Regards,
Sridar Venkatesan

Comment: Number of targets shouldn't have much impact but without more session log info we can't help. Possibly you're writing to tables that have indexes without dropping the indexes and using bulk load?

Comment: Hi Daniel,Load type is configured as Normal and we do have indexes. Let me see if i can drop the indexes and run the job with bulk load. Also, i see throughput is very less around 30 records per second and i had been noticing that sessions with more number of targets are always with low throughput. Should there be any Db settings which needs to be checked?

Comment: That will work for inserts (dropping index, bulk load then rebuilding indexes post load). For updates and deletes you need the indexes which your query utilizes to find the records. Its a balancing act but you can get rid of all indexes your job doesnt use on the target table and rebuild them after.  You can also improve load times by increasing the commit interval.

Comment: Commit interval is set to 100k.

Comment: Any chance of session log excerpts for better understanding? Even just the run statistics? E.g the bit which shows how long the threads were busy for?